# Supervised Learning and Poisson Regression

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I'm starting to studying something about Machine Learning and I've a doubt.
Given $Y$ the ouput, $X \in \mathcal{X}$ the input, let $L(Y,f(X))=(Y-f(X))^2$ the loss funtion.

Then $f$ should be the function that minimizes
$$
\int (y-f(x))^2 dF_{(X,Y)}(x,y)
$$
where $F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$ is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

So $\hat{f}(x)$ approximates $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$.

But often I read that $f$ is a function such that $Y=f(X)$ or $Y=f(X)+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a noise.

The problem I have is the following:

$i)$ If $Y\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ then if $f(x)$ is an approximation of $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$, so $f(x)$ can assume all positive values.

$ii)$ While if I assume $Y=f(X)$, $f$ **must map an element of the feature space to a natural number**, hence $\hat{f}:\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$.

The correct assumption is the first one, $\hat{f}(X) \approx \mathbb{E}[Y|X]$?

Comment: In your example what is the distribution for $X$.

Comment: The answer to the question depends on the distribution of $X$? Can you explain more? If the distribution of $X$ is unknown?

Comment: If $Y$ is conditionally Poisson, the conditional expectation of $Y$ (ie. $E(Y|X=x)$),cannot be negative, so $f$ cannot assume "all real values" (this might suggest that the least squares criterion is less than ideal in the case of the Poisson --- note that the variance of the Poisson changes with the mean; the plain least squares loss will tend to put too much weight on more variable/more uncertain values (which contain less information about $f$) relative to the less variable values (which contain more information about $f$). If getting an accurate estimate of $f$ is the issue... ctd

Comment: ctd... another loss may better achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I correct the phrase about the real values...however, let suppose I choose as loss function the deviance of Poisson distribution. I obtain as $\hat{f}(x)$ an estimate of $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x] \in \mathbb{R}_+$ right? I do not understand the meaning of $y=f(x) \in \mathbb{N}$...

Comment: I don't know where you got that from, but $Y$ is not the same thing as its mean. $Y$ does take values on the natural numbers, that part is fine, but consider $E(Y|X=x) = \frac12$ (a constant mean model) -- a Poisson random variate with mean $\frac12$ cannot ever equal its mean. So if you're reading something that actually says $Y=f(X)$ you're reading nonsense. Toss it out and read something else.